# How to test the source of image using just jest not enzyme in react if image source is imported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, imagesource

I have an image tag in react whose source is from my assets folder which is imported. I want to test it and match the source attribute having exactly same value. I have tried using `toHaveAtrribute('src',value)` but in this case test case is passing even if I pass a different image.
In a react component file the tag is following where "img1" is an image being imported from assets folder.

component.js file:

```
 <img src={img1}/>
```

In test.js file:

```
   const MockComp=(props)=>{
        const {image}=props;
        return <Router><Comp image={image}/></Router> 
    }


   test("Image testing", () => {
      render(
            <MockComp
             image={img1}
            />
        );
   })
        const image=screen.getByRole('img');
        expect(image).toHaveAttribute('src',`${img2}`);
```

If I pass "img2" being a different image than img1 in `toHaveAttribute()`, test case still passes. The requirement is to just use jest not enzyme. Is it possible to match both sources using just jest and react testing library.

P.S:  I have just started to write unit cases so I am still a Beginner in this jest testing.